# Is it possible to run a function on a Silverstripe template variable to format output?

Tags: php, templates, function, silverstripe

I've created a data model that includes a plain textarea entry field for an office address. I would like to do the equivalent of `nl2br($OfficeAddr)` when printing the data in my relevant Silverstripe template. As far as I can tell, their templating system does not support such functionality.

Am I missing something? Any recommended workarounds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Silverstripe 3 this would be best achieved by creating a [`DataExtension` class](http://doc.silverstripe.com/framework/en/reference/dataextension) (as opposed to overriding the class). (Note: this would be possible in 2.4.x as well, but the code would be quite different.)

Create a new class called `TextFormatter` which extends `Extension`:

```
class TextFormatter extends Extension { 
    public function NL2BR() {
        return nl2br($this->owner->value);
    }
}
```

Specify in config that the `Text` class should be extended with your brand new class. This can be done either in your `_config.php` file or (preferably) in a YAML file.

If you don't already have one, create a new file at `mysite/_config/extensions.yml` with the following content (or you can append this to your existing file):

```
Text:
  extensions:
    ['TextFormatter']
```

This just says "extend the class `Text` with the class `TextFormatter`" which will make our new `NL2BR` function available on all `Text` objects.

Now, in your templates you can simply call `$OfficeAddr.NL2BR` and the output will be run through your function before being output.

Note that I've assumed your model uses `Text` as the field type rather than `HTMLText` as a previous answer has assumed. If you are using `HTMLText` you can simply extend that class instead by changing your `extensions.yml` file as appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

IMPORTANT: This solution is applicable to SilverStripe 2.X. If you're using SilverStripe 3.0 - see SS3.0 answer on this page.

You'd simply add a getter to your model:

```
public function FormattedAddress {
    return nl2br($this->OfficeAddr);
}
```

Then call it in your template:

```
<p>$FormattedAddress</p>
```

**OR** - if you want to adhere to MVC, the more complex solution is...

Assuming you've used the HTMLText field type you could extend the HTMLText class:

Create a file called - Extended_HTMLText.php (or something similar) - add the following to it and save it into your code directory:

```
class Extended_HTMLText extends HTMLText {
    function NL2BR()    {
        return nl2br($this->value);
    }
}
```

Add the following to your _config.php file:

```
Object::useCustomClass('HTMLText', 'Extended_HTMLText', true);
```

Then you can call it in you template like so:

```
<p>$OfficeAddr.NL2BR</p>
```

This at least takes your view logic out of your model ;)

Comment: Great, that works for me. Not sure how it works for the separate content and display and logic folks, but they can never win... Thank you!

Comment: :) Just added an option that adheres to MVC. Is a little more complex though.

Answer (score 1):

This has been [**fixed** in SilverStripe 3](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/commit/4a158454d68d84a50f0c06ba1e8780bb64989ca5) (since May 2013) which all of these answers predate. Moving forward now, all `Text` and `Varchar` database fields are automatically converted using `nl2br()`.

So ... If you're silly like me and you ended up here, note that there's a possibility that you're actually outputting an `HTMLText` field but *thought* you were using plain text (because maybe you setup `->getCMSFields()` with a `TextareaField`).

Hopefully this helps future visitors!